# Como puedo evitar que salte un error MySQL al enviar una almohadilla por la url?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, api, lambda

Estoy haciendo una API y en el método GET cuando envío una almohadilla por la url me salta un error en el servidor (lambda). He probado en parametrizar el primer campo y funciona bien poniendo un valor directamente pero cuando lo hago la prueba en el postman, se genera un error.

https://example.com/dev/prueba?gameName=###&device=Mobile&siteRoom=room1&site=1

```
var query = `SELECT distinct WEBSITES.table.infoUrl, WEBSITES.table.logo, WEBSITES.table.name FROM
  ${mysql.escapeId('OGP.table')}, ${mysql.escapeId('WEBSITES.table')}, ${mysql.escapeId('WEBSITES.table')}, ${mysql.escapeId('WEBSITES.table')} where
  WEBSITES.table.infoUrl like ? and
  OGP.table.name like "%${event.queryStringParameters.device}%" and
  OGP.rable.name like "%${event.queryStringParameters.siteRoom}%" and OGP.rable.name not like "%DEPRECATED%" and
  OGP.rable.enabled and 
  WEBSITES.table.site = ${event.queryStringParameters.site} and 
  WEBSITES.table.url = WEBSITES.table.infoUrl and OGP.table.id = WEBSITES.table.tableId and 
  WEBSITES.table.pageId = WEBSITES.table.pageId LIMIT 500`;
  var result;
  var devuelvo={}
  con.query(query,["%chi#qui%"], function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error){
      con.destroy();
      throw error
    } 
    // console.log("GET: " + event.queryStringParameters.word)
    for (result in results){
      // console.log(results[result])
    }
    devuelvo=results
    
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final era un error de sintaxis, el "?" recibe el valor de [`%${event.queryStringParameters.gameName}%`] enviado por la url evitando problemas de caracteres e inyección SQL.